# BeautifulSoup + Requests >> AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Looked everywhere and I still don't know why it's giving an error. This was a YouTube tutorial and my code is identical so I don't know why it throws this 'NavigableString' error on the mentioned line below (I tried it in both Python 2.7 and 3.5).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url= "https://example.com"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "example"}) 

for item in data:
    print item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "ex"}) # Error line
```

---

**EDIT:** other usefull information

tutorial: http://youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk

example code in tutorial (time: 29:16): https://youtu.be/3xQTJi2tqgk?t=29m16s

url in tutorial: http://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/coffe?g=los%20angles%2c%20ca&q=coffe

Comment: `NavigableString` means plain text inside tag which can't have subelementes so it doesn't need `find_all`.

Comment: better in question add link to tutorial and url and we see if your code is really identical (and if it can work with current page - maybe something changed on page).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk

Comment: as always people don't know what means `"in question"` :)

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Keretto, it means that you should use magic `edit` button (between `share` and `close`) to add details to your question, but not to use comments for this purpose

Comment: every page is different so show (in question, not in comment) real `url` instead of `example.com` and real parameters instead of `example`, `ex`. I took your code and real url and `info` instead of `example` and it works without errors.

Answer (score 2):

In your 'soup' you may be expecting to get only tags, which is why you are calling .contents. If you called .contents on something that was not a tag then it would throw an error, which is happening to you.

The expectation that everything in the soup is a tag is what the problem is. Not everything in the soup is a tag, evidently from your error. There could be comments, or blank lines or random things. When these are coming through the loop and you call .contents on them they have no attribute that corresponds and throw an error, because they are not tags at all, they are NavigableStrings.

You should first separate in your loop tags from NavigableStrings. Do this:
`import NavigableString`. Then in your loop use this if else statement, or something to this effect (try, except, finally would also work if the statement was syntactically adapted for that clause)

```
if isinstance(object to test, NavigableString):
    Do something in this situation
else:
    Things coming through here are tags, do something with this
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
data=[]
for n in j.select('p')[1].contents:
data.append(n)
paras.append(data)
```

it will combine the navigation within the

like this

```
[["The government doesn't know how many people have died of ",
  <b>COVID</b>,
  "-19, in part because it didn't require nursing homes to report cases to the CDC. In some states, over half of deaths are in nursing homes."],
 ['As most of the world early awaits a vaccine for ',
  <b>COVID</b>,
  '-19, a smaller group of people scoffs. They could spell real trouble in the effort to build widespread immunity.'],
```

Answer (score -1):

> A tag’s children are available in a list called .contents:

children contains tag and NavigableString, in you case, `.contents[0]` is NavigableString which don not have `find_all` method

Comment: so should I not use '.contents[0]'?